# Why is this OrderBy not throwing an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a List of numbers that I want to order.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
```

It works fine if I do

```
.OrderBy(n => n)
```

Just for the heck of it, I tried

```
.OrderBy(n => "ASC")
```

It didn't work, but it was not throwing an error. And If I hover over OrderBy, the intellisense shows,

```
IOrderedEnumerable<int> IEnumerable<int>.OrderBy<int,string>(Func<int,string> keySelector)
```

Just curious, why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Why should it throw an exception?  You're just saying for every value in the list use the string "ASC" as the key value instead of using any of the actual values themselves.  Obviously using the same key for every value isn't going to produce a useful order.

Comment: Strange I don't see the same when I hover over OrderBy in intellisense

Comment: @HatSoft If you call it like OP called it (and obviously hover over that mention, not over another), you should see the same or something equivalent. What are you seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn't throw an error. You are telling it to compare using `"ASC"`, and it is doing just that.

Comment: That is, the *result* of the evaluating the function passed to OrderBy is used in the comparison .. this is why it's okay if it doesn't have the same type as the IEnumerable itself. (The function is implicitly `Func<int,string>`, which is what intellisense is showing.)

Answer (score 1):

This method compare keys using default comparer. The key for each element is  "ASC". Not illegal.

Answer (score 0):

As others note, this is because this is perfectly legal.  You could also do something like this:

```
 Enumerable.Range(0,20).OrderBy(x=>x.ToString());
```

You'll get the integers ordered... alphabetically.

```
0
1
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying to sort the objects by some value, where each value to sort by is obtained through each object; normally this would be a property or function of that object. You can think of it like a 'column' in a database or spreadsheet.

Ex:

```
var employeesByName = Employees.OrderBy(employee => employee.Name);
```

gives an enumerable of employee objects ordered by their name values. If you were instead to do this:

```
var employeesByConstant = Employees.OrderBy(employee => "ASC");
```

then you are getting an enumerable of employee objects that are ordered by a 'column' in which all of the values are "ASC". Depending on the sort algorithm used this may have no effect, or some arbitrary ordering.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but it doesn't work as you want, cause you compare using "ASC".

If you want to order numbers use:
`.OrderBy(i => i);

.OrderByDescending(i => i);`